# Pandas time series difference in time units with apply and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a product which has steps the product passes through.
i.e. data structure as:
product ID, Order ID, new value, old value, edit date.

I want the time difference and cumulative sum of time in days for product transitioning through our system.  i.e. total cycle time and inter step cycle time.

I wrote the following code which works well, but is still slow.  I am hoping someone might provide a faster solution, as it currently takes hours to process a YTD data set with 400 million process steps.

```
def f(df):
    df['diff'] = (df['Edit Date'].diff())/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    df['sum'] = df['diff'].cumsum()
    print  len(df)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('May 2017.csv')
    df['Edit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Edit Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
    df.sort_values(by=['Order ID','Edit Date',]  ,kind = 'mergesort', ascending=[1,1], inplace=True)
    df= df.groupby(['Order ID'])
    timediffference = df.apply(f)
```

This gives me what I want, but it's slow on large data sets, which typically exceed 20 million rows on a slow month.  Wondering if there is a way to do this faster against the entire date column per order group of steps, versus trying to utilize apply.  I tried using multicore, but found that a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby is quite slow when using apply. You should use functions implemented with the groupby object i.e. :

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('Order ID')['Edit Date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['sum'] = df.groupby('Order ID')['diff'].cumsum()
```

**Edit :** 
If this is not enough, you could also apply the diff on the whole dataset and not take the first row of every group. This should also be faster than the previous approach.

```
idx_wo_first = df.index.difference(df.groupby('Order ID').head(1).index)
df.loc[idx_wo_first, 'diff'] = df['Edit Date'].diff().loc[idx_wo_first] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['sum'] = df.groupby('Order ID')['diff'].cumsum()
```

Comment: I need it per product, so the first row every group.  Your first proposal is gold.  Thank you, this is so much faster.  It was starring me in the face the whole time.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Both of my codes produce the same output (although the second should be faster). In the second code, since I used diff on the whole dataset, the first row of every group is the difference between the first row of the group and the last row of the last group, so I need to filter those out. 
Also please consider accepting my answer since this is what you're looking for.